# Windows 10 - 'arp -d' as limited User

Tags: networking, windows-10, permissions, arp

I have some Windows 10 PCs joined to a Samba4 domain,
so most users only have a limited Account.
I added the useres to the local Group 'Network Configuration Operators' so that they are allowed to change inteface settings like their IP-Address,
but when these users execute arp via cmd it says permisson denied.

These users have to be allowed to execute:

```
arp -d some.ip.address
```

How can i accomplish that?

Comment: You are going ot have to share more information about your domain configuration specifically what restrictions you have configured surrounding the configuration of their network adapters.  Edit, your question, do not submit a comment

Comment: Added some info, hopefully enough.
If you need more info please be specific, i´m new to domains and don´t know which settings all exist.

Comment: `Network-Operators` is a custom local user group that doesn't exist in a default installation of Windows.

Comment: Not the exact name, it´s a german installation, changed the name again to maybe the proper name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the best solutions i have found:

When a user is in the Local *Network Configuration Operators* Group he is also allowed to use `netsh` or `arp -d` when the cmd shell is started as Admin, altough it is not a full admin shell it has evaluated permissons.
If you don´t want the UAC Password check you can login as admin and disable UAC, or create Scheduled Tasks with 'Execute with highest Permissons' and then run the task via cmd.